# Repair HDD using VmWare Player?

Tags: vmware

I have some old 40gb HDD that needs repair (bad sectors). "HDD Regenerator" is doing it's job, but it's PAINFULLY slow (5000 sectors per hour, about 14 000 000 of then need to be repaired!). The problem is that i have only one computer, and to use "HDD regenerator" i have to boot my computer from that particular CD. You probably get the point - i want to use my computer WHILE HDD is being repaired.
That's how i got an idea! I downloaded free "VmWare Player" and i'm planning to give it raw disk access and INSIDE virtual machine boot "HDD Regenerator" and repair my hdd while using my computer as always. But...i have never heard of something like that so i just don't know if it such a good idea :\ Any advice?

P.S. I have only one computer, so i can't use another to repair my disk, and i don't want to send my disk to "rescue company" because bad sectors aren't caused by mechanical fault, i'm pretty sure it's logical fault.

Comment: It's a 40GB drive.  Is it really worth it?  The only reason I can see is if there are important docs on it.  If that's the case,  why wasn't the drive backed up regularly?

Comment: @MBraedley, not everyone can just up and buy new parts.

Comment: @MBraedley, i have to admit - i did something STUPID. THAT was my backup drive! After bying new computer i didn't wanted to toss perfectly working HDD so i used 8yrs old drive as backup :(((((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that won’t work.

The whole point to using a boot disc instead of having HDDRegen do it from within Windows is that it needs to lock and have exclusive access to the drive. This is because it needs to be able to move files around if they happen to be in a bad sector.

It doesn’t matter what the VM thinks, the host OS has the drive in use (this is where your OS files are), so the guest cannot lock it (it will likely give an error).

But hypothetically, let’s say you somehow managed to trick the guest OS into thinking it has exclusive access. It is busy working away, moving files as necessary, thinking it knows the exact state of the drive and exactly where all files are. What do you think happens when the host OS writes to the drive? Data corruption is what.

---

Side note:

14 million bad sectors‽ That’s **18%** of the drive! Unless you are trying to recover data from it, then at that rate, just give up on the it and check the local classifieds (eg Kijiji, eBay Classifieds, etc.) to see if someone has a 40GB drive they can give you or an 80GB you can buy for a few bucks.

Check the drive’s [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) data with something like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php). That can give you an idea of the actual state of the hardware.

If you are *sure* it is merely a logical problem and not a hardware defect, then consider backing up the drive to another one (again check classifieds), then wipe the drive at a low level. Use a disk-editor or a hex-editor such as [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to open the drive, then fill the drive with 0’s to make it fresh and re-partition and format it.

Comment: I do have data on that disk. It's Maxtor DiamondMax +8 (slim). It has ONE platter and ONE head. When i scan it, it scans ok till 33% and then STALLS! I hear quiet "click" every 1/2 of second when it bumps at bad sector. From 52% to 100% everything is OK. BUT - after i use some healing software, it suddenly CAN scan past that magical 33% (currently everything is ok up to 33.55%). Damaged platter or head could NEVER be healed using "HDD regenerator" od similar software, right?

Comment: It could just be intermittent at this time and fail completely later on. I have a drive that had a bad sector. I flagged the cluster it was in as bad and continued to use it without problem for a year or so. Eventually, it did die. Again, check the SMART data for more detailed information on the actual hardware of the drive.

Comment: When i check SMART data i got scared - Windows 7 already told me that disk is dying :( I backed up (cut) everything i could salvage, but something left locked (for now)

Comment: Do you know which SMART field(s) were bad? That can give you an idea of how much longer it may have left. Did you simply move the files? It would have been better to clone the drive with something like [DriveImageXML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm). I’m not sure if you will be able to boot the new drive (at least not without extra work; it’s not as simple as simply copying files). As for the locked ones, you should be able to *copy* them.

Comment: Using "Acronis Disk Doctor" i got this: Reallocated Sectors Count - Fail, Reallocation Event Count - Degradation
Current Pending Sector Count - Degradation
Uncorrectable Sector Count - Degradation
Soft Read Error Rate - Degradation. Everything else is marked as "OK"

Comment: That means it has had trouble accessing sectors on it. There are some spare sectors on the disk so that bad ones can be remapped transparently, but if enough of them happen, it eventually runs out. Also, whatever problem caused the first bad sectors will usually continue to make new ones bad. Worse, uncorrectable sectors means that it could not even remap some bad sectors. In any case, I would start using a new drive right away and use this only for non-critical use with replaceable files like installing game or copying your movies, etc. Consider putting it in an external (portable) enclosure.

Comment: And chances to get out locked data? I heard that DM+8 is know to have firmware issues, does something like this looks like firmware issue? I already have some ideas about replacing PCB with PCB from identical drive (firmware code, model number etc).

Comment: It *might* be the firmware. If there is a firmware update, try that. Otherwise, the expense of finding an identical board is probably not worth it; it may be easier to find someone in your town who has a used drive you can buy or even have for free (I did exactly this last week). As for locked files, if they are just Windows files, you can copy them from the install disk (are you going to reinstall Windows anyway?) Either way, like I said, you should be able to *copy* (Ctrl+C) the files (not *move*). If that doesn’t work, then use [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to copy them.

Comment: No luck! Can't copy, can't open files. Like a broken cd... It's not system drive, it's my backup drive that sometimes (after shutting down my comp) i plug in and use as backup storage.

Comment: So it’s *only* personal files? Then you should be able to close whatever program is using the file. Try killing Explorer (in TaskManager) since it it often locks folders. Did you try Unlocker? If the file is not locked but just inaccessible, then it could be on a bad sector and the drive is unable to access it. You could try shutting down and trying again tomorrow when the drive has cooled. A lot of people have even sworn by [**freezing**](http://www.google.com/search?q=freeze+drive) their hard-drives to recover their data.

Comment: hahah no no noooo, sorry -> by "locked" i mean "file stuck on the hdd and can't do anything to read, move or copy it" :))) English is not my primary language, so i have some problems with "slang" :)

Comment: And "freezer trick"...i heard some VERY plausible reasons NOT to do this: inside of hdd there's clean air. Air has moist that will condensate after getting hdd ot of freeze :)

Comment: Yes, but what happens when you try to copy a locked file? Does Windows say *file in use*? If so, then use Unlocker.

Comment: No, by "locked" i mean files that remain on the drive and give me "Input/output" error when i try to read them. I have never used any software for protecting my data (like "Unlocker").

Comment: So you’ve already copied the files but cannot *delete* them from the original drive? Again, either **(1)** close the program that has the file open, **(2)** use Unlocker to view what program has an open handle to the file and force it closed and delete the file, or **(3)** use a program like [MoveLater](http://bitsum.com/other.php) to tell Windows to delete them the next time you boot.

Comment: No mate :) First: i was using files from the disk when suddenly i got "read error" while trying to open one file. I realized my disk is dying (strange "click" sound while trying to open SOME files) so i tried to salvage as much by selecting all files and trying to move them (cut) to another hard disk connected to computer. Some files passed, those that left on the old disk couldn't be moved, opened, copied. Same story when trying to move them using Linux, Windows, no matter. That's way i'm certain it's hardware-related problem.

Comment: Then it’s like I said several comments back: *If the file is not locked but just inaccessible, then it could be on a bad sector and the drive is unable to access it. You could try shutting down and trying again tomorrow when the drive has cooled.* Otherwise, you’ll just have to kiss those files goodbye and try to get another copy if you downloaded them or if you created them, see if you can find a copy on the other drive, a CD, in your online account, etc.